# How does .hgtags work when you update prior to when the tag existed?

Tags: mercurial

I have some tags:

```
❯ hg tags
tip                             2432:ed019577d04b
staging                         2430:8dfb436fbe46
production                      2408:8b016388cfec
```

Now I need to make a quick fix to production, so I `hg up production` and it takes me back to `8b016388cfec` as expected.

`hg tags` reveals that production still points to `2408:8b016388cfec` but `❯ cat .hgtags | grep 8b016388cfec` yields no results because I'm one commit *before* the tag existed.

So what is the actual Mercurial algorithm for determining `hg tags`? It's not merely parsing the `.hgtags` file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/962066/361714

Comment: @Tom Thanks! That nearly answers it, just had one clarifying question which I posted over there.